# Отдельные конвейеры (pipelines) для stdout и stderr в окружении POSIX

Tags: unix, sh, posix

Предположим, в окружении *POSIX* есть программа типа:

```sh
echo "stdout good"
echo "stdout bad"
echo "STDERR GOOD" 1>&2
echo "STDERR BAD" 1>&2
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в *stdout* и *stderr* получилось
соответственно:

```
stdout good
```

```
STDERR GOOD
```

То есть, нужно **перенаправить *stdout* и *stderr* в два
разных фильтра, сохраняя порядок вывода**.  Простой
`2>&1` использовать нельзя, ибо нельзя смешивать два
потока.  Перенаправление *stderr* в файл с последующей фильтрацией
и выводом в *stderr* тоже нельзя, так как теряется
последовательность строк.  С разными *named pipes* проблема скорее
всего та же.

Comment: `echo "STDERR GOOD" > /dev/stderr` хотя это символьная ссылка на /proc/$pid/fd/2

Comment: @PotroNik  Ни `/dev/stderr`, ни `procfs` частями *POSIX* не являются.  См. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/105635.  В *Bash* `/dev/stderr` — вообще [особое значение](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Comment: А `>&2 echo "STDERR GOOD"`?

Comment: @PotroNik  Как это поможет мне отфильтровать *stderr* отдельно от *stdout?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай 2 fifo и направляй туда потоки. Отправляешь дальше задачки фильтра в фон и можно писать.

```
mkfifo /tmp/err.fifo
mkfifo /tmp/out.fifo


grep good /tmp/out.fifo &
grep GOOD /tmp/err.fifo &

(
echo "stdout good"
echo "stdout bad"
echo "STDERR GOOD" 1>&2
echo "STDERR BAD" 1>&2
) 2> /tmp/err.fifo 1> /tmp/out.fifo
```

С пайпами

```
cat /tmp/out.fifo | grep good &
cat /tmp/err.fifo | grep GOOD &
```

Последовательность теряется в случае если один фильтр работает медленней другого. Но в случае когда читаем вывод программы, который медленнее самого медленного фильтра, должно работать нормально.